# What is some good software where i can write & execute JS code?

Tags: javascript, java, ide

I am looking for something like https://playcode.io/online-javascript-editor but software

Comment: "... but software" - do you mean a desktop app for Windows or Linux? What's wrong with an IDE ?

Comment: In addition to the answers already posted, you could try Eclipse, NetBeans, Atom, Brackets ... and many, many, more

Comment: aidenpethick, please answer Mawg' question, thanks! Please also read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/352/140 then edit your question, then we will reopen it.